# How to exclude images from regex email extraction

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I am using some email extractor software to (surprise surprise) extract emails from websites. It uses the regex:

```
[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]{3,65}\.[A-Z]{2,4}
```

But this churns out images as well as emails eg **_212000482_1@80xauto.jpg**

I can change this regex, but I cannot figure out how to exclude matches ending in .png, .jpg etc.

There is a lot of information on validating emails - and how hard this is - but all I want to do is exclude images from the result list.

Comment: What is the language you are using?

Comment: Why are you limiting the TLD's to 4 characters? See: http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db

Comment: I don't know the language - it is a piece of software (written by someone else) that searches text/html files based on a regex that can be changed by the user. Clearly the default regex is out of date - thanks Toto.

Answer (score 4):

## Description

In your sample text the undesired substring resembles an email address, but conveniently ends in `jpg`. So with a negative lookahead we can just exclude the filename extensions.

```regex
(?!\S*\.(?:jpg|png|gif|bmp)(?:[\s\n\r]|$))[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]{3,65}\.[A-Z]{2,4}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/mU7bO3/2

**Sample text**

```
droids@gmail.com _212000482_1@80xauto.jpg More.Droids@deathstar.com
```

**Sample Matches**

```
droids@gmail.com 
More.Droids@deathstar.com
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \S*                      non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                             and " ") (0 or more times (matching the
                             most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      jpg                      'jpg'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      png                      'png'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      gif                      'gif'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      bmp                      'bmp'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [\s\n\r]                 any character of: whitespace (\n, \r,
                               \t, \f, and " "), '\n' (newline), '\r'
                               (carriage return)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                               a "line"
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [A-Z0-9._%+-]+           any character of: 'A' to 'Z', '0' to '9',
                           '.', '_', '%', '+', '-' (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  @                        '@'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [A-Z0-9.-]{3,65}         any character of: 'A' to 'Z', '0' to '9',
                           '.', '-' (between 3 and 65 times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \.                       '.'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [A-Z]{2,4}               any character of: 'A' to 'Z' (between 2
                           and 4 times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Although it works perfectly in the tester it does not work when I plug it into the software - ironically it returns one extra example of an image. Unfortunately the software is a "black-box" there is no way to tell in what way (or with what language) it is using the regex. Can you think of an alternative formula that I could try?

Comment: Does it result in an error? Or does it kinda work for some matches and not others? What is the os type that your app is running in, do you know if java is required for your app?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting back to you. No there is no error. The app is running on a windows pc. Not sure if Java is required or not.

Comment: Great answer. Helped me a lot. About it working in tester but not in your code, I had a similar problem and it was because I pasted in the pattern but didn't add ", re.DOTALL | re.IGNORECASE" to my regex query. E.g. re.findall(pattern, string) did not match for me but re.findall(pattern, string, re.IGNORECASE) did match. Hope that helps.

Comment: This worked well for me as well, though I needed to add a " after the $ lookahead:

`(?!\S*\.(?:jpg|png|gif|bmp)(?:[\s\n\r]|$|"))[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]{3,65}\.[A-Z]{2,4}`